# Getting intermediate info. from PuLP

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

Getting intermediate result, while PuLP is trying to find the optimal and feasible solution.

As you know, solving Mixed integer Linear programming (MILP) cases may take a long time. I'm trying to get intermediate results from PuLP optimization package, while it is running. I know it is possible to do that in Gurobi, which is a commercial optimization package.

I'm not sure about the code I can use in PuLP package to get that information. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulp doesn't really have this interface (though if you use gurobi you can access the underlying solver object).

Comment: Thanks Stuart. No I'm not using Gurobi; am using the default solver in PuLP. thanks again.